# Python/Django avoid save an inline

Tags: python, django, save, inlines

I have inlines with a boolean parameter: `first`.
How can I edit the `save` method, to save only those inlines with `first = False`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is to edit the save function in the model itself:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.first:
        super(My_Model, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Of course, replace My_Model with whatever the name of your model is.  This will overwrite the default save function so that it will only run if first == False.